# Split rows sql in columns sql server and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I hav a table like :

[image: SQL Actual Table]

My Question is : It's possible to split thw 2 rows in a new Table with rhe sum Quantity for each CK Type?

Here a picture to show the result :

[image: Desidered Result]

Comment: Your CK type is fixed (only 2) or it can be more. If more you need to create dynamic Pivot

Comment: @Arturo Amalfi how about the other column, are they dynamic or fixed data

Comment: How do you know that QtyA/QtyB is 10/3 and not 3/10? Maybe creating two columns would be better

Comment: @PSK Ck could be s a or sL. But I get Qty only for A and S grouping by Serial

Comment: @Arturo Amalfi you do  the same in PIVOT option in Ms Access DB or Excel.Querying is not that easy i Think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is just 2 values for CK you can do this:

```
SELECT
    IDEME,
    MAX(CASE 
             WHEN CK='A' THEN Qty
             ELSE NULL
        END) QtyA,
    MAX(CASE 
             WHEN CK='A' THEN CK
             ELSE NULL
        END) TypeA,
    MAX(CASE 
             WHEN CK='S' THEN Qty
             ELSE NULL
    END) QtyS,
    MAX(CASE 
             WHEN CK='S' THEN CK
             ELSE NULL
    END) TypeS,
    Azienda,
    DataImport,
    Serial
FROM [Table] 
GROUP BY 
    IDEME,
    Azienda,
    DataImport,
    Serial
```

Comment: This looks like it would work but the formatting makes this unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I reformatted it - I hope it's more readable